# I get a null error when trying to navigate to a page in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, null, dart-null-safety

Application runs as normal but when i try to navigate to the product details i get this error
i have tried solving it by using the '!' sign and also casting as String but still get an error.

This is the code

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/products.dart';

class ProductDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // final String title;

  // ProductDetailsScreen(this.title);
  static const routeName = '/product-detail';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    final loadedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context)
        .items
        .firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == productId);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loadedProduct.title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And below is a screenshot of the error shown on the app

[image: Simulator image]

[image: screenshot of the page that creates the error below]

Answer (score 0):

accept nullable data from route.

```dart
late  final loadedProduct ;
  final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String?;

  if (productId != null) {
   loadedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context)
        .items
        .firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == productId);
  }
```

Comment: If needed, also do `Text(loadedProduct?.title?? ""),`

Comment: thank you sir for your answer but i still get an error when returning scaffold, this time not a run-time error. 

please pardon me as i am new to flutter and i'm still getting used to null-safety

`return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loadedProduct.title),
      ),
    );
`

i get the "undefined name 'loadedProduct'. error"

Comment: test update one